# proxy in fsi.exe (fsharp interactive)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, f#, proxy, fsi

I am trying to use the Build demo.
After adding   to the config files of devenv.exe and of fsi.exe, I dont have pb loading dll's anymore.

While I could modify the twitter samples to use my company's proxy, the freebase type provider does not seem to allow such override.

While my VS environment accesses the web without pb, FSI.exe does not seem to be able to go through my specified proxy. How can I force it to use by default a proxy I specify ? How is it that devenv.exe does not need any specific settings ?

PS : The following config, in the same directory that fsi.exe, did not work :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
     <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
         <proxy usesystemdefault = "false" proxyaddress = "ipaddress:portnumber" bypassonlocal = "true"/>
      </defaultProxy>

     <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
     <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok The default proxy was in the wrong config section.
should be in  instead of runtime.
Also should have http:// in front of ipaddress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   **<system.net>**
      <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
         <proxy usesystemdefault = "false" proxyaddress = "**http://**ipadress:portnumber" bypassonlocal = "true"/>
      </defaultProxy>
   **</system.net>**


   <runtime>     
     <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
     <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```